# Firebase User Data Update Error showing in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have Firebase, my data is showing fine, but when I want to update the value in firebase of field "firstname" is shows error.

```
var coll = await firebaseInstance.collection('userlist');
          coll.doc(authController.userId).update(
            {'firstname':"zeshan"},
          ).catchError((e){
            print('in catch');
            print(e);
          });
```

[image: enter image descrstrong textiption here]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: In addition to sharing the error that Elliot asked for, can you `print(authController.userId)` right before you use it in this code, and show the updated code and output?

Comment: I printed the (authController.userId), is shows the null value... 
Problem is I am using the GetX and that GetX is in route shows this in Run command.

[GETX] "AuthController" onDelete() called
[GETX] "AuthController" deleted from memory

Comment: By looking at the error and the value of `authController.userId`, null, it seems like you are referencing a value that doesn't exist which is the reason for the error. 

You may also want to check this [tutorial](https://dev.to/imransefat/firebase-authentication-with-getx-in-flutter-4ik8). 

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: I solved the problem, by signup the data into the Firebase on the single page, then It works for me.

Comment: @ZeshanUlHaque glad you fixed it. Do you mind posting your solution here? It will help the community in case someone encounters a similar issue. Thanks!